# Triangles in a graph via LP

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

I have a linear program and I can't formulate the objective function and constraints.

For a graph $G = (V, E)$ we may select a set $S$ of vertices of $V$. Each vertex carries a cost $c_v > 0$ if it is selected into $S$. For every triangle $T$ of $G$ (triangle: three vertices pairwise connected by edges of $V$) we incur a penalty $p_T$ if no vertex of $T$ is selected. The goal is to find a set $S$ of vertices such that the sum of total costs of vertices in $S$, plus the sum of penalties for triangles not covered by S is minimized.

Now this is a minimization problem, the objective function is $\min$ (something). I tried to use some notations:

- $c_i$ denotes the cost of vertex $i$ if vertex $i \in S$
- $x_i$ is a Boolean value: $1$ if vertex $i \in S$ and $0$ if vertex $i \notin S$

Or I could combine $c_i$ with $x_i$ and if $i \notin S$ then $c_i = 0$.

$Y_{a,b,c}$ - if vertices $a$, $b$, $c$ form a triangle

$p_{a, b, c}$ - penalty for triangle $T$ formed with vertices $a$, $b$, $c$

I think that the objective function should be something like $$ \min \quad \sum_{i=1} ^ n x_i \cdot c_i +\sum_{a, b, c = 1, a \neq b \neq c} ^ n  Y_{a, b, c} \cdot p_{a,b,c} $$ where $n$ is the number of vertices.

I'm not sure if the objective function is correct or not, I don't have any idea for the constraints (how to modulate the problem)..

Also, the problem suggest that we should binary variables (with values $0$, $1$)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to minimize $$\sum_i c_i x_i + \sum_T p_T \prod_{i\in T} (1-x_i),$$
which you can linearize by introducing binary variables $z_T$ and minimizing
$$\sum_i c_i x_i + \sum_T p_T z_T$$
subject to
$$\sum_{i\in T} x_i + z_T \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $T$}.$$

Comment: and what exactly is $z_T$?

Comment: $z_T$ is a binary decision variable, just like $x_i$.  The interpretation is that $z_T=1$ if $x_i=0$ for all $i\in T$.

Comment: and shouldn't be there a condition for triangle? I mean, new variables like $C_{a,b}$ = 1 if there exist a connection (edge) between vertex a and vertex b in the graph?

Comment: That is included in the definition of $T$.  You have one $T$ for each triangle in the graph.

Comment: and another question: why in your constraints ("subject to") the inequality is $\geq 1$?  shouldn't be $\leq 1$?

Comment: No, $\ge 1$ is correct.  This linear constraint enforces the logical implication $$\left(\bigwedge_{i \in T} \lnot x_i\right) \implies z_T.$$  That is, if $x_i=0$ for all $i\in T$, then $z_T = 1$.